# Angular 2 : Custom pipe breaking

Tags: angular, sorting, pipe

**Problem statement**

Custom pipe applied on both the angular expressions `{{fruits}}` & `{{fruits  | sortStringPipe:'asc'  }}` But it should apply only on the second one where i pass `pipe` symbol in the expression.

**Code base**

> mypipecomponent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cts-mypipecomponent',
  templateUrl: './mypipecomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mypipecomponent.component.css']
})
export class MypipecomponentComponent implements OnInit {

  fruits = ['mango','apple','banana','papaya','kiwi']

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

> Custom pipe (sort-string-pipe.pipe.ts)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortStringPipe'
})
export class SortStringPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    if(args === 'asc'){
      return value.sort()    

    }
    if(args === 'dsc'){
      return value.sort().reverse()
    }

    return value.sort();

  }

}
```

> mypipecomponent.component.html

```
Unsorted Fruits: {{fruits}}
Sorted Fruits: {{fruits  | sortStringPipe:'asc'  }}
```

**Output**

```
Unsorted Fruits: apple,banana,kiwi,mango,papaya Sorted Fruits: apple,banana,kiwi,mango,papaya
```

In output, we can see that it sorts both the expressions but it should only sort `{{fruits  | sortStringPipe:'asc'  }}`.

**Note :** If i pass any HTML element like `<hr>`,`<br>` between both the expressions then it is working but i do not want to use these elements between the expressions.

Comment: Hey that's a pretty fun bug ! I suggest you directly make an issue on Angular's repo, because it really is a bug. You already have the workaround in the meanwhile, there's not much we can do on SOF to help you.

Comment: Iam added my answer with stackblitz. Try this once and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Well, This might not be the most elegant solution but you can do the deep copying inside the pipe.

```
export class SortStringPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    let pipeArr = Object.assign([],value);

    if(args === 'asc'){
      return pipeArr.sort()    

    }
    if(args === 'dsc'){
      return pipeArr.sort().reverse()
    }

    return pipeArr.sort();

  }

}
```

Like @trichetriche mentioned this is an interesting bug. But since you are not keen to use `br` tags on html this try to use this one.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8jsqcf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: +1 for workaround but still my doubt is that as i am using pipe in second expression than why pipe applied on first expression.

Comment: i think since the result of the pipe get bind to the array and angular detect this as 2-way binding and change all instances of that property

Comment: May be you are true but why it is behaving differently after putting `<br>` in between the expressions. It is not changing all instances of that property after putting `<br>` or `<hr>`.

Answer (score 0):

Example:-,

Html File

```
<p>Unsorted Fruits: {{fruits}}</p>

<p>Sorted Fruits: {{fruits  | sortStringPipe:'asc'  }}</p>

<p>descending Fruits: {{fruits  | sortStringPipe:'dsc'}}</p>

<p>Fruits(Without Mention) : {{fruits | sortStringPipe}}</p>
```

Pipe File:-

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortStringPipe'
})
export class SortStringPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    if(args === 'asc'){
      return value.sort()    

    }
    if(args === 'dsc'){
      return value.sort().reverse()
    }
    return value.sort();
  }
}
```

Here is an working plunker i made for you,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pk2rta

output screen shot

[image]

I hope it's helpful,

Thanks,

Muthukumar

Comment: Please read the question carefully. With `<br>` element pipes are working fine. But if you remove `<br>` between two angular expression pipe applied to both expressions.

Comment: Hmm yes i read the question. Since pipes are used only within a tag only i think.In html without tag not consider as an html element.